# Crud com Eloquent Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-eloquent

Estou tentando fazer um CRUD com Eloquent Laravel em 2 tabelas com FK E PK, porém não estou tendo sucesso, já tem os models só falta a função CRUD mesmo, alguém pode me ajudar?

Esta é model com FK:

```
class crud_consignado_acordo extends Model
{
    protected $fillable = [
        'cpf',
        'valor',
        'formaenvio',
        'datavencimento',
        'numerocontrato',
        'id_consignado_registro',
        'id'
    ];

    protected $table = 'tb_consignado_acordo';

    public function registro()
    {
        return $this->belongsTo(crud_consignado_registro::class, 'id_consignado_registro');
    }
}

E esta com a PK:

    class crud_consignado_registro extends Model
    {
        protected $fillable = [

            'produto',
            'datareg',
            'nomeoperador',
            'celula',
            'usuariox',
            'aspect',
            'supervisor',
            'hora',
            'id'

        ];

        protected $table = 'tb_consignado_registro_operador';

        public function acordo()
        {
            return $this->hasMany(crud_consignado_acordo::class, 'id_consignado_registro');
        }
    }
```

A dúvida é como fazer o CRUD com Eloquent Laravel ORM nessas tabelas.

Comment: Sempre poste seu código para ajudar, o que você já fez no PHP? Qual a estrutura do seu banco? Em que você está tendo dificuldade mais exatamente?

Comment: Eu recomendo você tentar seguir a [convenção](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent#eloquent-model-conventions) dos Modelos Eloquent sempre que possível, isso facilita a manutenção do código por outros programadores e ainda evita ter que passar muito coisa por parâmetro, pois ele reconhece automaticamente as coisas baseadas na convenção.

Answer (score 0):

Amigo, é bem simples, são 2 CRUDS. Você pode fazer de 3 maneiras:

```
$ccr = crud_consignado_registro::create([
    'produto' => $request->input('form_produto'),
    'datareg' => $request->input('form_datareg'),
    'nomeoperador' => $request->input('form_nomeoperador'),
    'celula' => $request->input('form_celula'),
    'usuariox' => $request->input('form_usuariox'),
    'aspect' => $request->input('form_aspect'),
    'supervisor' => $request->input('form_supervisor'),
    'hora' => $request->input('form_hora'),
]);

//opcao 1
$cca = $ccr->acordo()->create([
    'cpf' => $request->input('form_cpf'),
    'valor' => $request->input('form_valor'),
    'formaenvio' => $request->input('form_formaenvio'),
    'datavencimento' => $request->input('form_datavencimento'),
    'numerocontrato' => $request->input('form_numerocontrato'),
]);

//opcao 2
$cca = new crud_consignado_acordo($request->all());
$ccr->acordo()->save($cca);

//opcao 3
$cca = new crud_consignado_acordo($request->all());
$cca->id_consignado_registro = $ccr->id;
$cca->save();
```

Seu exemplo aliás é bem parecido com o exemplo de `Post` e `Comment` da documentação do [Laravel: Inserting & Updating Related Models](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/eloquent-relationships#inserting-and-updating-related-models).

Veja também na documentação como recuperar dodos do request: [Retrieving Input](https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/requests#retrieving-input)

Espero que ajude.

Comment: Paulo Sakamoto, obrigado pela ajuda, mas meu formulário não está no padrão do banco de dados, como eu insiro individualmente cada valor?

Comment: Atualizei a resposta, mas basicamente é utilizar o método $request->input('nome_do_campo')

Comment: Olá  Paulo Sakamoto, muito obrigado pela ajuda, mas por algum motivo meu ajax ainda retorna falso, testei insert só em uma tabela assim:

Comment: Olá  Paulo Sakamoto, muito obrigado pela ajuda, mas por algum motivo meu ajax ainda retorna falso, testei insert só em uma tabela assim:                 

$ccr = crud_consignado_registro()->create([
                'produto' => 'teste',
                'datareg' => date('Y-m-d'),
                'nomeoperador' => $nome,
                'celula' => $celula,
                'usuariox' => $usuariox,
                'aspect' => $supervisor,
                'supervisor' => $aspect,
                'hora' => $horas,
            ]);

Comment: o sql bruto funciona, queria mesmo usar o eloquente pois deixa o código mais elegante e é mais fácil inserir na fk, assim funciona:
DB::insert('insert into tb_consignado_registro_operador(produto, datareg, nomeoperador, celula, usuariox,aspect, supervisor, hora)
                values (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)',
                ['teste', date('Y-m-d'), $nome , $celula, $usuariox, $aspect, $supervisor, $horas]
            );

Comment: Amigo, neste caso você tem que postar o código que você está utilizando para fazer o insert, acredito que algum método do seu controller.